# Collation issue in UNION Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I am working on a project where I am tasked to create a series of Union queries to compile data from different databases with the same structure. Some of these queries are very wide with large number of columns. And nope, I cannot change the number of columns. When I tried to create the query it gives a collation error. I can solve that easily with this command added to the column:

COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT

Now, the issue is that I have to do 50+ queries each with UNIONs to 5 or 6 different databases and 200+ columns. Every time I add that command to the column I also have to add an alias to the column or I lose the name. Any ideas if there is a more efficient way to do this without having to add the COLLATE clause to every column?

Comment: SQL-wise I don't have a good suggestion for you, but to automatically add the collate and alias to your columns, you can use regex. Take a list of your columns (each column on a separate line) and do a regex find and replace of: `^(.*)$` to `\1 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS \1`. Note that `\1` is the back reference, and your text editor might use `$1` instead.

Comment: how about create a `VIEW` with the `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of SSMS Column Editing mode. Here is how that would work.

1. Put every table column that you want to select *on a separate line*, and align the dots.
2. On the first SELECT line, type spaces until where I put the "cursor" (the pipe symbol) below, so that line becomes the longest of all the lines with column names:

```
SELECT P .AB    |
     , QR.CDEFG
     , S .HIJK
FROM P
JOIN QR ON ...
-- etc
```

3. With the cursor in that location, press <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>down</kbd> until you reach the last of the SELECT lines, this gives you a *tall multi-line cursor*:

```
SELECT P .AB    |
     , QR.CDEFG |
     , S .HIJK  |
FROM P
JOIN QR ON ...
```

4. Now type (or paste) `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS`, this text will appear on all lines at once:

```
SELECT P .AB    COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS |
     , QR.CDEFG COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS |
     , S .HIJK  COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS |
FROM P
JOIN QR ON ...
```

5. Now select exactly the text shown below, either using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>right/down</kbd>, or using <kbd>Alt</kbd> while dragging the mouse:

```
AB   
CDEFG
HIJK
```

6. Use *Copy* and then *Paste* the block of text at the end of the first line, with this result:

```
SELECT P .AB    COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS AB   
     , QR.CDEFG COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS CDEFG
     , S .HIJK  COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS HIJK 
FROM P
JOIN QR ON ...
```

For more on this, see e.g. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/06/06/sql-server-vertical-select-mode-feature-sql-server-management-studio/

Comment: wow, very cool stuff. thank you for sharing! Hidden treasure I guess!